# unity trigger not Working

Tags: c#, user-interface, triggers, unity-game-engine

My problem with unity 5.6 is that when my cube ("Player") goes through a trigger, it doesn't change the UI text like i want it to (nor does it print to log ("Trigger enter")). It is a bit over complicated, however it was intended for re use and so that is why there are variables for text object, string etc. The collision on the "Player" cube is continuous and all of what i have tried in similar threads has failed to fix this problem. The script can access and change the text, because the start function used to blank out the text until I added the if.

The following script is attached to the "Player" cube and the text is a canvas child:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class ChangeText : MonoBehaviour {

//    public GameObject TriggerEntity;
public Text TextEntity;
private string OldText;

// Use this for initialization
void Start () {
    if (PlayerPrefs.HasKey("oldtext") == true)
    {
        TextEntity.text = PlayerPrefs.GetString("oldtext");
    }
    else {

    }

}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {

}

void OntriggerEnter(Collider col)
{
    Debug.Log("Trigger Enter");
    TextChange(TextEntity, "There it is!");
}



void TextChange(Text text, string changeto)
{
    OldText = text.text;
    PlayerPrefs.SetString("oldtext", OldText);
    text.text = changeto;
}
}
```

Comment: capitalize the T in OnTriggerEnter()

Comment: Like @ryemoss said, spelling is very important when using the callback functions in Unity.